# What is considered a text node?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, textnode

Generally if there is text between tags in HTML, it becomes a text node. However, this is not always the case. Consider this example:

```
<p>
  <a href="hello.html">hello</a> <a href="world.html">world</a>
</p>
```

Here, the linebreak and 2 spaces between the `<p>` and the first `<a ...>` won't appear as a text node in the DOM, at least not in Chrome. `hello` and `world` will of course be text nodes. It would seem that sequences of only whitespace don't appear as text nodes, but that's not always the case: In this example, the space between the 2 links is a text node.

How does Chrome decide what becomes a text node?

Comment: Chrome doesn't decide. It's in the DOM specification which clearly--as far as specs go--points out how this is determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Chrome and you'll see the `firstChild` of `p` is `Text`:

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p')

console.log(p.firstChild.constructor.name)
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="hello.html">hello</a> <a href="world.html">world</a>
</p>
```

### Edit:

It seems you cannot even try that in Chrome as it throws `"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag."`

SO needs to update their snippet implementation as it obviously is broken as of now.

### Edit 2:

You can check it in Chrome here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQPdbz?editors=1111

Comment: Whoops! I was sure that if it isn't shown in the Elements view then it's not there...